# Format string to date with respect to locale

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

I know there are many questions about `JavaScript`, `String`s and `Date`s. But I could not find the solution to my problem.

I'm using the `dateTime` field from Spring MVC. The problem s that my backend expects a certain format of a Date (that's not fixed, I could change that if necessary)

```
@RequestParam(value = PARAM_SELECT_DATE) @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") final Date selectDate
```

But every browser parses the selected date differently which gives me a headache, e.g.,

```
de-DE: 13.02.2014
en-US: Feb 13, 2014
```

and I'm not able to transform every locale to a common date format in order to pass it to the backend.

I do not want to have (more) dependencies in my project, so how do I parse a JS date with respect to the locale, something like `Date.parse(date, locale)` would be nice.

Furthermore I don't want to parse the date in an ugly way such as

```
if (navigator.language == 'en-US') {
  var split = date.split(",");
  var splitTwo = split[0].split(" ");
  date = new Date(split[1], splitTwo[0] - 1, splitTwo[1]); // even here I would get 'Feb' instead of 02, another parse method would be needed
} else if (navigator.language == 'de-DE') {
  var split = date.split(".");
  date = new Date(split[2], split[1] - 1, split[0]);
}
```

and if more locales arise the method would have to extend the method.

**How do I get from a date string which is depends on the locale to a javascript date object?**

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175462/how-to-convert-localized-date-to-standard-date-in-javascript

Comment: Uses an external library

Answer (score 0):

You can preformat date on client:

```
+(new Date())//timestamp
(new Date()).toISOString()//ISO string
(new Date()).toGMTString()//GMT string
...
```

Comment: HOW do i get from a String which is LOCALE dependent to a DATE? That's the question

Comment: Can javascript code `new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString())` works on every browse? I think browser may know how to parse localeDateString.

Comment: If you are creating date object on client (I assume so because of locales) you can convert it to common format before sending to backend (as in my answer). You will be able to load this in future using new Date(<date_string_from_backend>) At least thats how I understood your question.

Comment: I was NOT able to create a `Date` object because I have localized `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

Globalize's [date parsing module](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-parser.md) will probably do what you need !